# Swift: Cannot convert the expression's type '() -> () -> $T1' to type '()'

Tags: swift, closures

I've defined a very simple function that will perform a block on the next run loop iteration:

```
func NextRun(f:() -> ()){
  let observer = CFRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler(nil, CFRunLoopActivity.Entry.rawValue, Boolean(0), 0) { obs, act in f() }
  CFRunLoopAddObserver(CFRunLoopGetMain(), observer, kCFRunLoopCommonModes)
}
```

Simple enough, and I can sort of use this, so long as I directly assign a named closure to it whose signature matches the expected argument.  Ex:

```
  func alertUser() {
    self.masterRouter?.didReceiveMessage(userID)
  }
  NextRun(alertUser)
```

However, what I cannot do is pass it a closure.  This fails:

```
  NextRun{
    self.masterRouter?.didReceiveMessage(userID)
  }
```

I get the error:

> Cannot convert the expression's type '() -> () -> $T1' to type '()'

I've tried various syntaxes, but always get the same error.  It appears Swift is confusing the closure signature with the function inside the closure... or am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated from UIAlertController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761835/self-navigationcontroller-popviewcontrolleranimated-from-uialertcontroller)

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Better leave this up though.  I did a lot of searching and never found that question.

Comment: Because you didn't know what to search for :) and the error message is misleading